# leaflet getBounds() errors

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to getBounds of dynamically added markers to the map.  My goal is to dynamically add markers to a map and have the view automatically zoom to fit the bounds of all the markers on the map.  Below is my current code and what I have tried so far:

The starting point is an array of lat & lng:

The web page offers a list of addresses and checkboxes that a user can select and deselect.  When the desired addresses are selected the user can click view on map and the makrers will appear on the map (this is working perfectly, I just can't get the view to zoom to the bounds of these markers)

I have a loop that pulls the lat and lng for each checked address and pushes it into an array like this:

```
latLng.push(42.9570316,-86.04564429999999);
latLng.push(43.009381,-85.890041);
```

...this is in a loop so it always contains the desired amount of values and outputs this:

```
latLng = [42.9570316,-86.04564429999999,43.009381,-85.890041,43.11996200000001,-85.42854699999998,43.153376,-85.4730639,42.8976947,-85.88893200000001];

var thisLatLng = L.latLng(latLng);

console.log(thisLatLng); // this returns Null

mymap.fitBounds(group); //  returns Error: Bounds are not Valid

mymap.fitBounds(group.getBounds()); // returns group.getBounds() is not a function
```

I have also tried this as a starting point:

```
latlng.push(L.marker([42.9570316,-86.04564429999999]));
latlng.push(L.marker([43.009381,-85.890041]));
```

...this is contained in a loop that results in the output below

```
latLng = [L.marker([42.9570316,-86.04564429999999]),L.marker([43.009381,-85.890041]),L.marker([43.11996200000001,-85.42854699999998]),L.marker([43.153376,-85.4730639]),L.marker([42.8976947,-85.88893200000001])];

console.log(latLng); // this returns makrers with the correct lat & lng above

var group = new L.featureGroup(latLng);

console.log(group); //this returns a Null featureGroup

mymap.fitBounds(group); // returns Error: Bounds are not valid

mymap.fitBounds(group.getBounds()); // returns Error: Bounds are not valid
```

I am at a loss on how to make this work I have tried several answers posted on stackoverflow and attempted to try and follow the documentation but nothing seems to give the desired outcome.

**Update**

I removed `latLng.push(L.marker([42.9570316,-86.04564429999999]));` loop and replaced with the following:

I created a featuregroup with `var group = new L.featureGroup();` then added markers to it in the loop by using `marker.addTo(group);` this pushed all of the markers into the featuregroup as I would expect but was unable to get bounds.

```
mymap.fitBounds(group.getBounds()); // returns Error: Bounds are not valid
```

here is what `console.log(group);` outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think at all that

```
latLng = [L.marker([42.9570316,-86.04564429999999]),L.marker([43.009381,-85.890041]),L.marker([43.11996200000001,-85.42854699999998]),L.marker([43.153376,-85.4730639]),L.marker([42.8976947,-85.88893200000001])];
```

Can work. In leaflet you can't just create a variable and say that it's a marker object. You need to use method like `L.marker()`

What you need to do is create a single marker and add it to a `featureGroup`

```
var group = new L.featureGroup();
for (var i = 0; i < yourMarkers.length; i++) {
    L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(group);
}
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

`group` will now contains multiple markers.

And you can also try this :

```
var coordinates = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < yourMarkers.length; i++) {
    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]);
    coordinates.push(marker);
}
var group = new L.featureGroup(coordinates);
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

**UPDATE**

The concerned function was this one :

```
function showResult(lat, lng) { 
    var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]) 
    .bindPopup('yourPopup').on("popupopen", onPopupOpen).addTo(group); 
    map.addLayer(group); 
    map.fitBounds(group.getBounds()); 
}
```

You only need to add the `fitBounds()` inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  there are two issues that this does not resolve.  1 is my fault as I did not explain the starting point well enough and I will update my question to better explain how this is being updated dynamically. 2 because this is dynamically being created and the values are always changing I cannot statically and marker1, marker2...etc like `var group = new L.featureGroup([marker1, marker2, marker3]);` I have to be able to use a variable containing the array to make this happen like the document suggest is possible.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to have a simple working jsfiddle ? Would be a lot more easier for me to help you fix this.

Comment: I have been working at one but this page is very complex with a lot of moving parts so I am trying to figure out how to pull out whats needed and relevant but the problem is everything is connected to make the user's life easier.  I don't want to post a fiddle that's 2000 lines of code, I don't feel that would be helpful.

Comment: I understand no problem. I will try without it. So in your loop you have to iterate on each position to create a marker with `L.marker(yourPosition`. Still in this loop, at the end : add this marker to your `group` (which is defined outside the loop) instead of pushing it to an array. I will edit my answer

Comment: I tried this but received the same error.  I have updated my question to show the trial and result.

Comment: I've updated too. And what's inside `group` if you use a console.log ?

Comment: it returns the featureGroup object with a layer for every maker added to it

Comment: I tried my second example and it work perfectly. Into coordinates I have : `(4) [e, e, e, e]` (so 4 objects) and inside group I have `e {_layers: {…}, _leaflet_id: 192, _initHooksCalled: true}` with my layers

Comment: Mine is returning `e` and inside that `e {options: {...}, _latlng: o.LatLng, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 25, _eventParents: {...}}` and inside that `..._latlng: o.LatLng {lat: #, lng: #}...` with # being an actual coordinate.

Comment: added console.log to question

Comment: Well this is exactly what we want. In your console type : `map.fitBounds(group.getBounds())` If your group object is correct, normally it will autocomplete with the method getBound() when you start to write it

Comment: I just pulled `group.getBounds()` out and did `var thisbounds = group.getBounds();` then `console.log(thisbounds);` returned an object but no values inside of it.  Could getBounds be whats failing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155512/discussion-between-baptiste-and-craig-howell).